# Noob question about F# function parameter where the parameter is a list

Tags: f#

I'm trying to play around with creating functions in F#, In the image below, I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of floats and sum the values in the list. I don't know how to pass a list as parameter in a function so I tried this to get the head of a list but the code doesn't work:

```
let sumlist l=
    printf "%f" l.Head
```

Then I see some people does:

```
let sumlist l:float=
    match l with
    | [] -> 0.0
    | e::li -> e + sumlist li
```

So is `l:float` the way you pass a list to a function? so like `l:string` would be a list of string?

But I saw list l has `l.Head` function to return the first element in the list(As it seems that we can't access arbitrary elements in the list like an array) but

```
let sumlist l:float= 
    printfn "%f" l.Head
```

gives type mismatch error.

I also don't understand the recursive code provided, I don't understand this line

`| e::li -> e + sumlist li`

What is ::? and Li?

Thank you for clarifying this for me!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your first example doesn't return anything and that's because you're calling printfn which prints to the console instead of returning your types. e :: li here represents a list where e is the head and li is the rest of the list. The :: here lets the compiler know that you want to deconstruct the list.

```
//fully annotated
let s (l: float list) :float = 
    l.Head
//here the types can be inferred without any annotation
let rec sumlist l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> 0.0
    | e::li -> e + sumlist li

s [0.7]
//returns 0.7

sumlist [0.4;0.5;0.6]
//returns 1.5
```

In my first example if you try and remove the type annotations you'll notice that you get an error. This is because l.Head's type is ambiguous otherwise did you call l.Head on a list of strings, floats? In the sumlist function I provided you can see that I didn't need to annotate, and this is because I'm adding them up and that constrains the types.

Personally when starting I highly recommend always annotating the types. `(l : float list)` or `(l: list<float>)` is a way to say my input is a list of floats, and `:float` at the end how we say the return type is a float. You'll notice I put a rec keyword on our recursive function, it's better to explicitly declare whenever you make a recursive function.

Comment: I would add that matching over the list is the proper way to consider all possibilities. Using the ``Head`` property (or ``List.head``) will throw an exception if the list is empty. Next, the ``rec`` keyword is actually required for a recursive function as it puts the function's name in scope for its body; if you don't use it, trying to make a recursive call yields a compiler error. Finally, you may want to search for some F# tutorials; 'F# for Fun and Profit' is a great one with loads of material to work through many aspects of F# programming.

Answer (score 1):

### Syntax questions

> So is l:float the way you pass a list to a function?

No. Most of the time the compiler can figure out that you are passing a list without annotating the parameter as a list, but when it doesn't, you annotate is

```
l : 'a list // where 'a is generic type
// OR
l : float list // where type is specified as float
```

> What is ::? and Li?

When pattern matching a list, [] matches to empty list, which here is used as the recursion end criteria. The other match separates head (e) from the rest of the list aka tail (li). If there is only one item in list, then li evaluates as [].

Additional note for your recursive code: You are missing the recursion keyword *rec* eg.

```
let rec sumlist ...
```

### Recursive function implementation

The easiest way would be to use the [sum function of List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.sum%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) eg.

```
[0.4; 0.5; 0.6] |> List.sum // Returns 1.5
```

But, if you want to create this function yourself, consider using [tail-recursion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/what-is-tail-recursion) for better performance and to avoid stack overflow with bigger input lists.

```
let sumlist (values : float list) =
    let rec sum (acc : float) (remaining : float list) =
        match remaining with
        | [] -> acc
        | head :: tail -> sum (acc + head) tail
    sum 0. values
```

Which is called

```
[0.4; 0.5; 0.6] |> sumlist // Returns 1.5
```

The difference here to a normal recursion is that each recursion calculates its own values and is not dependent on other recursions yet to come to finish its calculations.